# Нужно/можно ли поставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Вопрос о запятой. Без нее получается неоднозначно, как "казнить нельзя помиловать".

Смысл предложения: на косметические средства наносят эко маркировки, они означают, что состав был проверен экспертами, и он безопасен. В этом удобство: проверять скрупулёзно состав косметики с наличием эко маркировок не приходится. Он уже был проверен экспертами.

А вот само предложение:

> Такие экологичные средства легко узнать без скрупулезного изучения составов и этикеток (запятая) по эко маркировкам — знакам гарантии безопасности и экологичности выбранного средства.

Без запятой создаётся впечатление, что состав и этикетка изучаются по эко маркировкам. Что бы это ни значило. 
Хотелось бы с помощью пунктуации убрать эту "ловушку" и сделать смысл очевидным с первого прочтения.

Пожалуйста, прокомментируйте. Можно ли ставить запятую и будет ли ошибкой ее не ставить?

Answer (score 2):

**Варианты редактирования:**

(1) Такие экологичные средства не требуют скрупулезного изучения составов и этикеток, **так как легко узнаются по экомаркировкам** — знакам гарантии безопасности и экологичности выбранного средства.

(2) Такие экологичные средства не требуют скрупулезного изучения составов **и этикеток и легко узнаются по экомаркировкам** — знакам гарантии безопасности и экологичности выбранного средства.

**Пояснение:**

Запятая там действительно нужна, но при наличии обособленного оборота текст читается не очень ясно.